# How does one "read" the shutdown state of a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

On Linux *and* hopefully Winsock.  One can shutdown the read and or write channel on a socket with "shutdown" ( this might or might not have some latency if things are in the buffer ??? )

Is there a way to read this state? from a socket that hasn't yet been "closed" and released.

ie:  int shutdownState = ::is_shutdown(sock);  // or something like it.

Comment: Yes, a socket's read and write channels can be independently shutdown on Windows. But there is no socket function in any platform to get the current state of each channel. The only way to know if a channel has been shutdown is to attempt an I/O operation in the channel and see if it fails with a shutdown-related error (`WSAESHUTDOWN`, etc)

Comment: awww - seems so messy the error reported in some cases is "invalid file handle" on Ubuntu  there seem to be issues depending on the thread timing in terms of which error is reported.  I mainly don't want to log the error if the program had deliberately shut down the read channel to abort the waiting read thread.

Comment: typically, in that case, you should wait on more than just the socket, like an event object or pipe, so that you can send a signal to the thread when you want it to abort before you then shutdown or close the socket. Shutting down the read channel doesn't guarantee that a pending read already in progress will abort.

Comment: only works for windows.  I either need to have a short timeout and loop and/or shutdown read from another thread to abort a waiting socket in linux,